# How to monitor new likes on Facebook page with WebHooks?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks

I have some questions regarding the Facebook WebHooks.

1)I would like to get notified every time a fb page gets a new like/post etc. I understand this is the feed field. I assume I have to be the facebook page admin for this?

2)What is the exact body of the update object that I will receive in this case? Will it contain information about the liker? Say his/hers email?

Comment: Yes, you need admin access to subscribe to page updates. And no, of course you don’t get someone’s email just because they liked something, that would be ridiculous.

Comment: @CBroe Can you please post the format of the update object? I need to know what fields it includes. Thanks.

Comment: Documentation for webhooks has some examples. What exact data structure you will get, depends on what fields you subscribed to and for which one specifically you are getting the current update. Implement some form of logging in your webhook script, so that you can inspect the structure.